# Visual Studio: Error DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073D1F]

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10-universal

Getting this error when trying to debug a Windows Universal App. Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting), error 0x80073D1F is ERROR_REGISTRATION_FROM_REMOTE_DRIVE_NOT_SUPPORTED. But in my scenario, I'm not using a remote drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using a remote drive, but I have a folder on a local drive for sources that's mapped as a separate volume. I guess that makes it appear to the app deployment logic like a remote drive. I navigated to the folder on the local drive (not the mapped volume) and opened the VS solution from there, and the deployment works.