# WinUI 3 Deploy failed on blank project from template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, winui-3

I've created a brand new C++ WinUI 3 project in Visual Studio 2022 (fully up-to-date) on a Windows 11 PC, developer mode enabled. Without changing anything, I build: everything ok - and run on local machine: fails, with error

DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073D1F] Deployment operation failed.

I don't even know where to begin with this one - I've tried searching for "DEP0700: Registration of the app failed" but none of the results are anything to do with "Deployment operation failed", and adding that to the search doesn't change the results.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Doc:[Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting)

0x80073D1F: Remote drives are not supported. Use \server\share to register a remote package. Whether you used a remote drive? I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68696109

Comment: Yes, I'm using a remote drive, but it's mapped to Z:. I don't understand the resolution described in the troubleshooting article - it says "use server/share" but I can't find any documentation on that - at least, none that doesn't invoke Server Manager, which I don't seem to have.

Comment: You could try to navigate to the folder on the local drive (not the mapped volume) and opened the VS solution from there.